# Change a data field in a Data Extension based on send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for a way to change a data field in Marketing Cloud based on a successful email send.

For example I have a DE with "Welcome Email 1 Complete" as a field, when I send a email and it successful sends i'd like to update this field to "Yes".

Is there ampscript function that can tell when the email was send successful?

Comment: Adam's Answer (query in automation) is much more comprehensive and will make sure it is only those that truly were successfully sent, but if you don't need it to be on the nose accurate and want it immediately, you can just add an UPSERT Ampscript function into the email to update that field each time the email is created. If you normally have clean data, the margin of error is pretty insignificant.

Comment: How would you set that code up? I'm familiar with upsert but would you need any other code to identify when it sends? Or would you just place it at the top and let it run?

Comment: You would just put it at the top.  I usually run the AMPscript function IsEmailAddress as an IF statement with the Upsert inside just in case it comes from a source that doesn't verify this prior to sending.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/), looking at records in the [_Sent](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_sent/) System Data View, to update your `Welcome Email 1 Complete` column.

You could include a query like this in your Automation to set those flags for sends occurring on the previous day.

```
select
1 as 'Welcome Email 1 Complete'
from WelcomeDE w
inner join _Sent s on (s.subscriberkey = w.emailaddress)
inner join _job j on (j.jobid = s.jobid)
where j.emailName = 'NAME OF YOUR EMAIL'
and j.pickuptime < cast(getdate() as date)
and j.pickuptime >= cast(getDate()-1 as date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam, i'm gonna give this a shot and see if I can get this to work.